# TwiML: Is there a way to hint Twilio that the user is going to say numbers?

Tags: twilio

I'm writing an IVR application where the user can input a code that consists of numbers. For this I'm using `<Gather>` with `input` with the `dtmf speech` values.

While testing using speech, I've noticed that many times the number is not understood and something else is returned. Is there a way to help Twilio understand that the input is going to be a series of numbers similar to what is done with the normal [hints](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-hints)?

Comment: just my thoughts , i imagine Twilio didnt think there potential for improvement on something  as ubiquitous as numbers.

Comment: Are you looking for single numbers read out ("one, five, three, seven") or the cardinal number ("one thousand five hundred and thirty seven")?

Comment: I'm looking to identify single numbers, as in "one, five, three, seven". It would be nice to have it for combinations too as in "fifteen thirty-seven" or "nineteen sixty-four" but that's something else